# Name Error - Name is not defined.... but it is

Tags: python, nameerror

So I'm writing this little program for a class, I'm basically to the end and I keep getting the error:

```
averageWeekMiles = int(totalMiles)/ int(weeksRented)
NameError: name 'weeksRented' is not defined
```

I have defined it in the same area where I defined the `daysrented`, I cannot figure out why it keeps telling me the name is not defined...

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
rentalCode = input('')
print("(B)udget, (D)aily, or (W)eekly rental?")


if rentalCode == 'D':
  daysRented = input('')
elif rentalCode == 'W':
  weeksRented = input('')



if rentalCode == "D":
  print('Number of Days Rented:')
  print(rentalCode)
elif rentalCode =='B':
  print('Number of Days Rented:')
  print(rentalCode)
elif rentalCode == 'W':
  print('Number of Weeks Rented:')
  print(rentalCode)
if rentalCode == 'D':
  print(daysRented)
elif rentalCode == 'B':
  print(daysRented)
elif rentalCode == 'W':
  print(weeksRented)


budget_charge = 40.00
daily_charge = 60.00
weekly_charge = 190.00  


if rentalCode == 'B':
  baseCharge = daysRented * budget_charge
elif rentalCode == 'D':
  baseCharge = int(daysRented) * int(daily_charge)
elif rentalCode == 'W':
  baseCharge = weeksRented * weekly+charge



print("Starting Odometer Reading:")


odoEnd = input('')
print("Ending Odometer Reading:")

print(odoStart)
print(odoEnd)

totalMiles = int(odoEnd) - int(odoStart)
print(totalMiles)

if rentalCode == 'B':
  mileageCharge = totalMiles * .25


averageDayMiles = int(totalMiles)/ int(daysRented)


if averageDayMiles <= 100:
  extraMiles = 0
elif averageDayMiles > 100:
  extraMiles = averageDayMiles - 100
  mileCharge = .25 * float(extraMiles) * float(daysRented)




averageWeekMiles = int(totalMiles)/ int(weeksRented)

if averageWeekMiles > 900:
  mileCharge = 100 * int(weeksRented)
elif averageWeekMiles <= 900:
  mileCharge = 0


amtDue = baseCharge + mileCharge


print(mileCharge)
```

Comment: It's better to initialize `daysRented` and `weeksRented` in the beginning and then assign them user input values. Same goes for every variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only define "weeksRented" if the "rentalCode" is "W". If the rentalCode is "D", "weeksRented" is never defined but it is used, returning your error.

Comment: I actually thought about this as I was troubleshooting.  Before that if 'rentalCode' is W line I put in weeksRented = input(' ')  and that triggered another error stating EOF error farther down. odoStart = input('')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line